# strange pin on edge

Tags: tikz-pgf

Trying to respond this question [anchor point on a self loop (to draw a line from that anchor point)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219890/9335), with answer like "you may use pin for this ..." I discovered some strange (for me) behaviour of pin on node in middle of edge. The pin is styled like the edge before it.

Is this a bug or a feature ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle, draw, font=\scriptsize] (n1) {is this ...};
    \path (n1) edge[loop,>=latex] node[pin={[purple]90:a bug ?}]{} ();
    \path (n1) edge[bend right=40, thick,-latex] node[pin={[red]above:or feature ?}]{} +(3,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this expected? A node on an edge picks up the options passed to the edge (e.g. if the edge is passed `red`, the node will pick up that colour). And a pin draws an edge from the node to an additional node, so presumably options passed to the original edge will carry over here, too. Don't know, though...?

Comment: @cfr putting the color on the path should be inherited by all elements on the path, but putting options on one edge is not inherited by the next edges in general, no ? And it looks strange, for me, that when the edge is bent, the pin bends too.

Comment: I don't know. It isn't exactly the next edge. It is sort of a sub-edge, isn't it? A kind of edge-of-edge-of-path.

Comment: @cfr yes and no ;) pin for me is an attribute to the node, not to the edge that is used to position the node. No ? I think that some "reset" is forgotten here ... but probably I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me this is not a feature, because:

- a pin is a node accessory, and whatever the way we position a node, the pin edge style should not change;
- this is confirmed by the edge width, for example. As we can see in the code, if some edge is thick, the corresponding pin edge is not thicker.

But this **is not a** (deep) **bug** either.

- It is understandable that the pin edge that is in the scope of another edge, inherit all styles that are not explicitly set. And the default style of the pin edge is `help lines`. So the line width being set to `very thin` is not inherited, but the `bend`, which is not set, is inherited.
- This behaviour can be easily, and in a standard way, corrected by the following setup:

`\tikzset{every pin edge/.append style={bend left=0,>={},->}}`

With this, the result of the question's code become:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{every pin edge/.append style={bend left=0,>={},->}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [circle, draw, font=\scriptsize] (n1) {is this ...};
  \path (n1) edge[loop,>=latex] node[pin={[purple]90:a bug ?}]{} ();
  \path (n1) edge[bend right=40, thick,-latex] node[pin={[red]above:or feature ?}]{} +(3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** So I can answer now [the original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219986/9335) ;) ... almost, because there seems to be a bad behavior of "dashed" on the pin's edge :(

Comment: (+1) I like this answer. I don't know whether this is a bug, a feature or neither, but this seems like a good response in the absence of a definitive reply from the package author!